# Measure to indicate overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, statistical-significance, random-forest

I am working on a binary classification suing random forest with 977 observations and 15 columns. (75:25 class portion). Imbalanced dataset..

I got the output like below for train and test datasets

**Train data**

[image]

**Test data**

[image]

While I understand that test data performance is poor. But for train dataset it is too good.

q1) How do I know whether it is overfitting on train dataset? Just because it is doing good on train and poorly on test dataset, does it mean it has overfit the train dataset? **I wish to build a baseline model using default parameters, so, am not doing hyperparameter tuning.**

q2) Why is it not normal to have too good performance on train data?

q3) If there is any measure to indicate overfitting of the model, that would be helpful.

q4) Am using hold out (train-test split) for training and test the model due to my dataset size of 977 records. Is there anything else that I can do to make sure that my model is not overfit?

q5) When I run decision tree, I also get similar output shown below. So, confused as to whether it is overfitting or not

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Ofer-a's suggestions are a bit confusing in this case (they seem geared more towards gradient boosting or a neural net), because RandomForest does not overfit "over time" or with more trees. This is because the trees are independent of one another - so running 500 trees will not increase overfitting any more than doing 50.

Moving to directly answer your questions.

Q1) You're correct. You can only tell that a model is overfitting by comparing train set performance to test set performance. By definition, "overfitting" is when a model fits itself to the *noise* of the training data and therefore doesn't generalize well to unseen data (because it fit the noise which, of course, is random/inconsistent).

A small note here: You mention you want to build a baseline model with "default" parameters, without hyperparameter tuning. There isn't really such a thing as "default" parameters. Your software package will have defaults, yes, but these are arbitrary. I would recommend tuning your hyperparameters. RandomForest usually does a good job even without tuning, so improvement probably won't be dramatic, but hyperparameter tuning is pretty easy to implement, so why not?

Q2) It is **very** typical to have amazing performance on training data. ML models are usually super complex, so it's rare that they don't manage to fit the training data super well. Again, this isn't a bad thing on its own. It's just if the training set performance is much better than test set, you know overfitting is occurring. I would **highly** recommend using cross validation to a) tune hyperparameters and b) use the performance on the out-of-sample folds in cross validation as error estimates (they're not perfect, but they're something. For any more advanced readers, please look into **nested** cross validation for real OOS error estimation), and compare your training set performance vs. validation performance, and then validation performance vs. test set performance. It will give a clearer picture of your situation.

Additional note: I think it's fair to say that you can pretty much always expect some degree of overfitting with machine learning models. This intuitively makes sense. as you would expect this super sophisticated algorithm to find **some** kind of pattern within the training data (regardless of whether this pattern is noise or not). The question with overfitting is simply "how bad is it in my case?". Again - I highly recommend cross validation.

Q3) I believe I answered this within my first two responses. Your measure of overfitting is how much better the model does in training than in test set.

Q4) Cross validation. It's an absolutely essential tool and especially with a dataset that's pretty small, I cannot recommend it more. It doesn't stop all issues, but it helps you tune your hyperparameters and get better error estimation before running your model on your test set (and therefore biasing your whole experiment as you go back and forth between repeated runs on test set, correction, run on test set, correction etc.)

Q5) Yes, that looks like it's also overfitting. However, decision trees are notorious for this (overfitting). I would recommend sticking with RandomForest, and using cross validation.

I hope this helps understand overfitting!

Next step: Generally speaking, overfitting is reduced by reducing the complexity of the model. For RandomForest, this means limiting the depth or number of nodes within each tree of the RF (so the algorithm is forced to make more simple trees).

Comment: thanks @Vladimir Belik. upvoted. much useful

Comment: I have question wrt to your response for Q4. When you mean cross-validation, how can I apply CV on a dataset where I have already split them based on `train` and `test` due to encoding. Meaning, I split my dataset so early in the data preparation process as I have to transform categorical variables in to numerical variables. To avoid data leakage, I split them as train and test (and then apply the encoding techniques)

Comment: I was referring this link for reading about CV. https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/validating-machine-learning-models-scikit-learn

Comment: This link suggests that we should pass `y1` during CV split. However, wouldn't that lead to data leakage? In the above link, they pass full dataset `X1` and `Y1`. Whereas I should pass just my `ord_train_t`, `y_train`. `Ord_train_t` represents the ordinally encoded input data (after train_test_split)

Comment: @TheGreat I'm a bit confused by your comment, unless you're referring to what you and I discussed before where some of your variables are based on other variables in the "past". Generally, you would do CV by splitting up *just* your training data, leaving test data as final hold out test set. So you'd do k-fold CV by splitting training data into folds, etc. If you're talking about some features needing to be based on other features that must be 'already known' to avoid leakage, then you would have to re-calculate these features with every CV fold. It's a bit of a hassle, but not crazy complex.

Comment: @TheGreat If I understood you correctly but my comment doesn't make sense, we can always discuss in more detail. To be honest, I'm a bit confused about the references to make to the link. I will read later in more detail.

Comment: This is what I tried based on suggestions of tuning hyperparameters and doing CV. But got some unexpected results. Any thoughts on this. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/563531/when-is-it-okay-to-accept-overfit-model-for-production

Answer (score 1):

Some comments:

1. Overfitting can be identified by looking at the train loss and the validation loss over time. The classic overfit behaviour is that at the beginning, there is a decrease in both train loss and validation loss, but then train continue going down and validation loss is starting going up. What you showed can be overfitting but not necessarily, and it can be also because of other reasons.
2. Very good performance on train set is not necessarily a bad thing, sometime you have enough features that explain the data very well. However in many cases this is a sign to overfitting or fitting the noise. Fitting the noise is bad, because it improves the train loss but hurt generalization and causes bad validation loss. Consider a simple example of a line + noise. The perfect prediction with train loss = 0, which will fit all the points including the noise. But obviously, this is a bad prediction because new points will have higher error.
3. If indeed you have overfit, you can add regularization to your model, or try early stopping (at the point that the validation loss start going up).

Comment: thanks, upvoted, Do you know how can I find the loss for my model using random forest for train and test dataset? Based on your 2nd point, look my model is overfit on train data

Comment: Yes overfitting is definitely a possibility. Not sure about random forest loss over time.